# Having trouble switching python versions using pyenv global command

Tags: python, macos, path, homebrew, pyenv

I have installed pyenv on Mac using homebrew and downloaded the version of Python 3.7.9. Everything works except when I use `pyenv global 3.7.9`, `python3 -V` still gives me version 3.9.7. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please run `pyenv versions` and make sure that PyEnv knows about version `3.7.9`.  I don't remember for sure, but I don't think that just installing a new Python version via `brew` is enough.  I think you have to run some PyEnv command to tell PyEnv that the new version exists.  I don't remember just what the syntax is for that.  I think PyEnv can install new Python versions itself as well.

Comment: I typed pyenv install 3.7.9 and it shows that the version is installed right. However the global command still doesn't change the version.

Answer (score 8):

Run the commands below in your terminal before running `pyenv install <VERSION>` / `pyenv global <VERSION>` / `python --version`

```
eval "$(command pyenv init -)"
eval "$(command pyenv init --path)"
```

You may need to re-install your required python version

To avoid running these commands in every session, add the commands to your shell profile file `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`

Entire `.zshrc` that works as of March 2022:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PIPENV_PYTHON="$PYENV_ROOT/shims/python"

plugin=(
  pyenv
)

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(command pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Comment: why do you use `eval`?

Answer (score 1):

For Arch Linux, these worked, as similarly answered by @Eladio:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PIPENV_PYTHON="$PYENV_ROOT/shims/python"
pyenv init -
command pyenv init --path
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do so by searching the process bin path (`which python3` will give you the path of your python3.9.7, `which python3.7` will give you the path of your python3.7) and by adding an alias into your `~/.bashrc` (assuming you're using in from your terminal) you should be fine

Comment: The whole point about using pyenv is that you can use *multiple* versions of python automatically, so you are stripping off the auto-part of it, elsewise I am fine with that ;)