# Local pyenv python version ignored

Tags: virtualenv, jupyter, pyenv

I want to use Notebook with a previous python version as Pytorch works with 3.8

I have installed 2 python version :

```
$ pyenv versions
* 3.8.10 (set by C:\Users\Guillaume\Documents\Python\Pegasus Tutorial\.python-version)
  3.9.6
```

I have set 3.8.10 local to my notebook folder as I want to run it with older python version.

Though my notebook cell returns this :

```
!python --version
Python 3.9.5
```

When I run python --version inside the folder it returns 3.10.5 and not 3.8.10 as expected

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71188577/having-trouble-switching-python-versions-using-pyenv-global-command