# Why Python version is not been shown correctly when using pyenv for Python environments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv, macos-sonoma, pyenv-virtualenv

I have installed pyenv in MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1 version. I have added the following to `~/.zshrc` and `~/.bashrc` files according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71188577/having-trouble-switching-python-versions-using-pyenv-global-command):

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PIPENV_PYTHON="$PYENV_ROOT/shims/python"

plugin=(
  pyenv
)

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(command pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

The problem is that when opening a new terminal after activating a pyenv through `pyenv activate 3.10.7` and asking `python --version`, I got: `zsh: command not found: python`. But, if I use these commands:

```
eval "$(command pyenv init -)"
eval "$(command pyenv init --path)"
```

When asking again `python --version`, `Python 3.10.7` is shown in the terminal.

I wonder why this is not working correctly after I added the `$PATH` command in ~/.zshrc and ~/.bashrc files.

Comment: Set things up in your `~/.profile` instead of `-/.bashrc` on macOS.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, it does not work at all. I need to run `source ~/.profile` every time I open a new terminal.